# Django Admin automatically logout after get data from user

Tags: django, django-forms

I am facing an problems in django admin panel. My django admin panel autumatically logout When any user  submitting contact-form. How to stop automatically logout? I am facing this problems after add session in my views.py. here is my code:

**#views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponseRedirect,redirect
from contact.forms import ContactForm
from contact.models import Contact
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt 
def home_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
    name = None
    obj = None
    if request.method == "POST":
      
       contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
       if contact_form.is_valid():
          name = request.POST['name'] 
          email = request.POST['email']
          subject = request.POST['subject']
          message = request.POST['message']
          save_details = Contact(name=name,email=email,subject=subject,message=message)
          save_details.save()
          request.session['name'] = name
          request.session.set_expiry(1) #if I remove this line then it fix the logout problems but not clearing the session after refresh. 
          return redirect(home_view)
          #return render(request, 'index.html',{'message_name':name}) 
          
       else:
          print("not submitted")
          
           

    else:
       contact_form = ContactForm()
         
  
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':contact_form,'message_name':obj})
```

**#urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from pages import views


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.home_view, name="home"),
        
    ]
```

**root urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from pages import urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

**#index.html**

```
 {% if request.session.name %}
                <div class="centerTest">
                     <h1> Thanks  {{ request.session.name }} for your message. We will get back to you very soon</h1>  
                </div>
{% else %} 

                <div class="contact__container bd-grid">
                    <form action="#contact" method = "POST" class="contact__form">
                              
                        {% for error in  form.non_field_errors %}
                          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                               {{ error }}
                          </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        
                        <label>Name:</label>  
                        {{ form.errors.name }}
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="contact__input" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.name.value }} {% endif %}">
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        {{ form.errors.email }}
                        <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="contact__input" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.email.value }} {% endif %}">
                        <label>Subject:</label>
                        {{ form.errors.subject }}
                        <input type="text" placeholder="optional" name="subject" class="contact__input" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.subject.value }} {% endif %}">
                        <label>Message:</label>
                        {{ form.errors.message }}
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="message"  id="" cols="0" rows="10"   class="contact__input" >{% if form.is_bound %}{{ form.message.value }} {% endif %}</textarea>
                         
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="contact__button button">
{% endif %}
                    </form>
```

my django madmin panel autuomatically logout when any user submitting contact-form. How to stop this? anyone please help

Comment: Your code has `request.session.set_expiry(1)` in the `home_view` view which invalidates the current session after one second, logging out the user

Comment: if I remove this line then it fix the logout problems but not clearing the session after refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid using session for this purpose, but if you want to do it, then remove it from the session at the moment when you are about to display the "thank you message"

```
def home_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
   if request.method == "POST":
       ...
   else:
       # you are about to display the "thank you message", so remove it from session here
       # check if name is in session
       if 'name' in request.session:
           # not sure from top of my head if session allows `pop`, if not then get value first and then remove it
           thanks_name = request.session.pop('name')
       else:
           thanks_name = None
       contact_form = ContactForm()
         
  
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':contact_form,'message_name':obj, 'thanks_name': thanks_name})
```

how to do it without using session? Use [Django Messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/) which is built exactly for such use-cases. First you [Add Message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message) in view, and then you [display it in template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages):

```
from django.contrib import messages
if request.method == "POST":
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Thanks for your message. We will get back to you very soon')
```

template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

also why do you use `@csrf_extempt`? Add `{% csrf_token %}` into your form instead.

Comment: Just getting this text "Thanks for your message. We will get back to you very soon" But I aslo need to be show "Name". How to show name inside text message

Comment: you already know how to get it from post data, so put it inside the sentence via string interpolation or string concatenation or `.format()` or f-string, that's up to you. When in doubts you can always google something "python string interpolation", there's plenty answers online already.